# A step in Toda's computation of a Cotor

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, cohomology, classifying-spaces

I am trying to understand a proof from Toda's paper [Cohomology of classifying spaces](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/advanced-studies-in-pure-mathematics/Homotopy-Theory-and-Related-Topics/chapter/Cohomology-of-Classifying-Spaces/10.2969/aspm/00910075). The step I am stuck on is at page 96. Here is the setup.

We work with cohomology with $\mathbb{F}_2$ coefficients. Let $G$ be a compact Lie group, $\Gamma\subset G$ be a central subgroup which is isomorphic to either $S^1$ or $\mathbb{Z}/2$, let $E_1:=H^*(B^2\Gamma)\otimes H^*(BG)$ with differential
$$d:=(\mu\otimes 1)\circ (1\otimes \theta\otimes 1)\circ (1\circ \phi),$$

where $\phi:H^*(BG)\to H^*(B\Gamma)\otimes H^*(BG)$ is the coaction map (i.e. the map induced by the multiplication $\Gamma\times G\to G$, which is a group homomorphism as $\Gamma$ is central), $$\mu: H^*(BB\Gamma)\otimes H^*(BB\Gamma)\to H^*(BB\Gamma)$$ is the multiplication map, and $\theta$ is the $\mathbb{F}_2$-linear map defined as follows: if
$$H^*(B\Gamma)=\mathbb{F}_2[x_2],\qquad H^*(BB\Gamma)=\mathbb{F}_2[z_2,z_3,z_5,\dots,z_{2^k+1},\dots]$$ (where $z_2=0$ when $\Gamma=S^1$), then
$$\theta(x_2^{2^i})=z_{2^{i+1}+1}, \qquad \theta(x_2^j)=0 \text{ if $j$ is not a power of $2$}.$$
The point is that the cohomology of $(E_1,d)$ is the Cotor from page 95 that Toda wants to compute, in order to obtain his main results.

Simply put, I don't understand the reasoning at page 96, which from (4.2) deduces Theorem 4.1. Let me be more specific. Assume that $G=U(n)$ (see picture below for the other cases), $\Gamma=S^1$, and let $q$ be the highest power of two dividing $n$.

At page 96, right before the statement of Theorem 4.1, it is claimed that

$$(*)\qquad H^*(E_1,d)=H^*(C\otimes B,d)$$

where $C=\mathbb{F}_2[z_3,\dots,z_q]$ and $B=\{a\in H^*(BG): d_i(a)=0 \text{ for all $i\geq q$}\}$, where the $d_i$ are the components of $\phi$: $\phi(a)=\sum x^i\otimes d_i(a)$. (So $C\otimes B$ is a subalgebra of $H^*(BB\Gamma)\otimes H^*(B\Gamma)$, and the differential on $C\otimes B$ is the restriction of $d$.) The proof of $(*)$ is supposedly in the few sentences leading up to the statement of Theorem 4.1, but I can't quite follow it.

Here is a screenshot of page 96. I am pretty sure that uploading a single page from a paper is fair use, but if it's not let me know and I will immediately remove it.
[image]

Comment: Just a small remark: the center of $SU(n)$ is not $S^1$ but $\mathbb Z/n$.

Comment: Thanks, I meant $U(n)$.

Comment: It will be easy for people to explain if you can quote here "(4.2)", "Theorem 4.1" and  "the few sentences leading up to the statement of Theorem 4.1 (most people can access only to the first page of the linked book).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know,  I added a picture.

Comment: Basically what Toda says is that "provided that ... is closed under the differential" (which he doesn't prove)  you can remove the part the part you know to cancel out in the cohomology of the fiber and that of the base from the computation, and you are left with the expression he gives in Theorem 4.1.

Comment: I agree that this is probably what he meant. My problem is that since theta is linear but not a homomorphism, I don't understand how $\mathbb{F}_2[a_q]$ 'cancels out' with the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_2[\theta(x^q),\theta(x^{2q}...]$ (note that $\theta(a_q)$ as written by Toda does not make sense), and also how this cancelation interacts with $B$.

Comment: That is why he computes also $d (1\otimes a_q ^{2^r})$ as well.

Comment: @user43326 could you elaborate? Note that say $d(1\otimes a_q^2)$ is not necessarily equal to $\theta(x^{2q})\otimes 1$ modulo $B\otimes C$, there could also be $\theta(x^q)\otimes b$ for some $b\in B$ among "lower terms". How do you get rid of that?

Comment: @user43326: Why not make your comments an answer?  Even if you only have time to write it briefly, it’s still a very good start, and if it needs expanding afterwards, an answer can be edited (by you or others), which is much clearer than a back-and-forth discussion in comments.

Comment: @user43326 Thank you for your messages, but unfortunately the part that is obvious to you is exactly what I am stuck on.

Comment: Just a suggestion: the title of this question seems very “generic” to me (I for one almost didn’t look at your question because I guessed it would likely be an exercise from Hatcher or something). I suspect you might get more views by experts if you made the title more specific. Even something like “question about an argument of Toda” might be an improvement, though I suspect something even more specific might be feasible.

Comment: @user42024 These "error terms" don't change the structure of the quotient.